# Database Design for a Multiplayer/Single Quiz game

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

I saw a lot of questions here but no one fits with my problem. I'm trying to create an ER model scalable, and if I want to add more data don't break almost anything, so what I've trying to create is :

There are 2 types of users, let's say Admin and Worker, and they have different roles.

Admin can do a CRUD of questions, and also can create a room where the users can join to play together (this is just a name, something like Kahoot! does) but maybe is a good idea to create more attributes inside of it like, WHO is playing in this room, POINTS for everyone but let's talk it afterwards when I show you the design.

Ok the thing is, on my design I have :

Table User which contains :

```
_id
username
password
date_creation
```

This is a default one, but then I'm wondering how do I define the Role if it's an Admin or a Worker, something like isAdmin:true and then I check this Bool? Or I can create another table that is Role and connect it to User table?

But maybe I have to create a table for both, I mean there's an Admin which has a password, and some functionalities and then ther'es the user Worker which has another password and another functionalities.

Then I'd like to have the Question table where contains :

```
_id
question_name
answers[1,2,3,4]
correctAnswer or answers because it can be multi option chooser
topic
isExamQuestion
dificulty
```

Then the Room table should contains :

```
_id
name
capacity
type (game can be as a group or solo) that's why this attribute
exam (This should be a flag to know if this question is for an exam or not (It can be for EXAM or PRACTISE)
ranking (This is the top X from 1 to X)
don't think if I have to add the winner here because if I get the position 0 from ranking I get the winner...
```

There's a table named Topic as well, if my question have a topic then I can select the question by Topic. An example of Topic should be Math so user can do only exams or do tests with math questions.

```
_id
Name
Questions[...]
Then I have to store like a historic about what are the questions worker has answered correct and what did not, to make some statistics, but I need to store some historicals for Admin to see in this topic the average that Workers have failed more is : Question23 (for instance) something like that.
```

What I'm missing, could you try to help me to figure it out how to make this design better?

NOTE : I'm using Spring for server side, Angular for Frontend stuff, and Android for App, I can change anything to work faster/better with this database though.

### EDIT

There's the flow of the game if you need more details and if I'm explainted wrong .

Admin flow

1. Create questions (with different kinds of answers like True/false, with a checkbos (single and multianswer), text, etc...)
2. Create a "game" where workers can join (This is mostly programming stuff) but it should be a room with attributes there, like id of the room, maxNumber, type (exam), and store historicals, theres also a type of game (for instance, images, videos, etc..)
3. See statistics about Workers it means see how many answers they answered correct, failed, see per topic (This is like joins and stuff,  but the design has to be good done)
4. See historic of the exams that he did before with all of the information (participant, score, time, stuff)

And the Worker flow is

He can practise means that he's answering questions randomly or by topic (every single answer should be saved for statistics and to avoid repeat the ones he respons correct), also he can do exams (not multiplayer) just an option that Admin can check if the question is part of an exam or not.

And then the room stuff, he can join with the Id.

If you need further clarification let me know and I'll reply you as soon as possible.

Comment: What does "better" look like? Faster? Easier to code with? Easier to change?

Comment: Hello @NevilleKuyt thanks for your interest, yes from the start I have something similar to the [MaximFedorov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181058/database-design-for-a-multiplayer-single-quiz-game/54278049#54278049) and I'm looking to another possible solution that could me more scalable means that if I want to add more stuff I do not need to change lot of tables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, your system has three logical parts (modules):

- users module that contains user data and implements authentication and the authorization of user actions
- questionnaires module that includes management of questions and answer
- questionnaires history module that contains history by each user

Database design of those modules can look as follows
[image]

**USER MODULE:**

**role** - contains user roles in the system

- id - unique identifier of the role
- name - the role name, for example, admin, worker, etc.

**user** - contains users and information about roles were assigned to them

- id - unique identifier of the user
- username
- password
- role_id - identifier the role was assigned to the user

**QUESTIONNAIRES MODULE:**

**topic** - contains question themes

- id - unique identifier of the theme
- name - a name of the theme

**question** - contains questions

- id - unique identifier of the question
- topic_id - topic identifier of the question
- text - content of the question
- is_exam_question - exam question or not
- type - type of answers (boolean, checkboxes or etc.)
- difficulty

**answer** - contains all answers of questions

- id - unique identifier of the answer
- question_id - identifier of the question that contains the answer
- text - content of the question
- is_correct - flag that means the answer is true or false

**room** - contains information about rooms

- id - unique identifier of the rum
- name - name of the rum
- capacity - the maximum number of workers which can join to the room
- type - room type: group, solo or etc.
- learing_type - room type: exam, practice or etc.

**user_in_room** - contains information about users which were joined to the room

- user_id - identifier of the user that was joined to the room
- room_id - identifier of the room
- score - current score of the user in the room

**HISTORY MODULE:**

**user_question_history** - contains information about questions which were answered by the user

- user_id - identifier of the user
- room_id - identifier of the room where the user answered questions
- question_id - identifier of the question that was answered by the user
- score - user score by the question

**user_answer_history** - contains information about answers which were chosen by the user

- user_id - identifier of the user
- room_id - identifier of the room where the user answered questions
- question_id - identifier of the question that was answered by the user
- answer_id - identifier of the answer that was chosen the user

Usage of this schema gives the ability to build different reports. For example, you can display the result of all users by room

```
SELECT r.id,
    r.name,
    u.username,
    ur.score
FROM room as r
LEFT JOIN user_in_room as ur ON ur.room_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN user as u ON u.id = ur.user_id
WHERE r.id = <id>
```

Or you can see detail information about answers of the user

```
SELECT 
    q.text,
    a.text
FROM user_in_room as ur ON ur.room_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN user_question_history as uqh ON ugh.user_id = ur.user_id AND ugh.root_id = ur.room_id
LEFT JOIN question as q ON q.id = ugh.question_id
LEFT JOIN user_answer_history as uah ON uah.user_id = ugh.user_id AND uah.room_id = ugh.room_id AND uah.question_id = ugh.question_id
LEFT JOIN answer as a ON a.id = uah.answer_id
WHERE ur.room_id = <id> AND ur.user_id = <id>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm waiting for more proposals, but I'm wondering for instance how do I get the history for rooms ?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS What data should the history contain?

Comment: Imagine that you are a teacher and then you do an exam, 10 days ago you want to check it again, so what would you want to see there? Like data, how many students participated, notes, answers for each question by every student, etc... that's what I mean, but I'm wondering if this is something about joins and stuff that database design....

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I attached several queries to the answer

Comment: Awesome, let me take a look and go deeper to see if something is missing, thanks for your time Maxim :D

Comment: what do you think with the answer proposed by TiyebM? Makes sense in your diagram?

Comment: If you delete *is_correct* from the answers, and add the correct answer's key to questions, you can use referential integrity constraints to ensure every question has a correct answer.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS If you need to keep information about profile and exam you can do it.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden Yes, you are right, but one question might have many right answers.

Comment: Maxim, I'm missing something, there's a room which contains an "exam", do I have to modify the table? I mean admin can create a room so then assign to it an exam to show later on.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Well, you should create `exam` table and add a link to an exam in `room` table

Comment: And this is a personal question, do you think is missing something in my design? I mean, the one that you did in your answer do you think there's something missing?

Comment: That's the proposal for `type` in question, let's say I can have a questions for : `exam`, `study`. `whatelsemore`

Comment: And now I'm wondering, if I want to do different questions like "test", "true/false", "short answer" how would do this with this design? Could you try to guide me please? (for sure I'll put the bounty on your answer, but those are some missing stuff that I'm wondering)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS If you want to do different types of questions you can set them to `type` column (for example like as ENUM) and display different input fields  which depends on this type in client side

Comment: So from now is ok? I mean I can detect from client side that the question is true false answer and the next one is test one and the next one is a small answer?  I mean at the time admin creates the question I can choose for exame if it's a test I can choose 4 answers and put 1 or 2 as a correct, one? right?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yes

Comment: Thanks for yout effor man,really,onequestion if I want to add an explanation for each question do i have to put another parameter in the table? or create another table with id name etc?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS an explanation of a question might be added to question table

Comment: user_in_room and history one doesn't have primary key @MaximFedorov? I'm creating the schema for those and I do not see the primary key I have the option to put : `NOT NULL` `PRIMARY KEY` `UNIQUE` `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` are they `FOREIGN KEY`, right?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS user_in_room has user_id and room_id. Those params identify a record. Those params might be the composite primary key.

Comment: Is there any way to create this ER and get the sentences SQL to create for postgresql?? Did you create the ER for the answer by the way?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if you're certain you'll only have to possible types--both now and in the future--a simple bool isAdmin in your user table will work nicely. Everything else the admin does can be handled from the programming side. No need to clog up your db.

That said, if there's even a small chance you will have other types of users in the future, Maxim's answer is the way to go. That way, adding another role such as "Editor," for instance, is a simple as adding a record to the "Role" table. In fact, adding 1000 new types users is as simple as adding records to your "Role" table. Because you already have a table that you look to for the role, your code doesn't have to worry about all the possible types of users (which is a pain if you have a lot of them), only the ones it needs. The db is handling the rest.

One drawback to Maxim's answer is that it takes more work to implement in the db, and more work to view/update the role of the user.

To implement in the db, you need to create a whole extra table and make sure it's linked properly. This isn't hard, but, especially if you're new to dbs, is extra work that might not be worth it to you. This also means, from a maintenance side, that you have another table to keep tabs on. Not a huge deal, but, again, something to think about.

From the code side, this creates extra chores as well. For one, the user type is no longer directly in your users table--an ID is. This means when you want to know the name of the user type, you will have to either a) query the db for that user type based on the ID you have, or b) join the 2 tables, which can be tricky at times. Updating the role also has similar chores.

Again, these aren't huge problems, just things to think about. It might not be worth the extra work if you will only have two possible options.

So, in short, a boolean will work and is simple to implement, but is not scalable. Maxim's answer is quite scalable and makes future expansion easier, but somewhat harder to implement and maintain. You'll have to make the decision what you prefer.

Comment: Harder. Not too terribly hard. To implement, you'll need to make a whole other table ("Roles") and link it properly, etc. And then, every time you want know the role a user or update the role of a user, you'll have to join the tables together. It's not too hard, just and extra step every time. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Profile` table with `one-to-many` with `User` table, this way if another privelege you want to apply, just add new profile entry:

`User` table:

```
Id
Username
Fullname
Profile_id
...
```

`Profile` table:

```
Id
Name
Description
```

`Exam` and `Question` tables are related with `many-to-many`, to break it you will have a third table `Question_Exam`:

`Question_Exam`:

```
 id_exam
 Id_Question
 Answer(provided)
 Id_user(taking the exam)
 IsCorrect(boolean, to avoid farther queries )
 date
```

`Topic` and `Question` are `one-to-many`

`Question` table:

```
 Id
 Name
 Answer(The correct one)
 Id_topic
```

The other structure is fine.